# Objective-C += equivalent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry for the newbie question, but i cannot find an answer to it.

I have a simple operation. I declare a variable, and then i want to loop through an array of integers and add these to the variable. However, i can't seem to find how to get a += equivalent going in Objective C.

Any help would be awesome.

Code:

```
NSInteger * result;
for (NSInteger * hour in totalhours)
{
    result += hour; 
}
```

Comment: You need to mention how totalhours is initialized and populated.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What is `totalhours`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the syntax for dereferencing is different in Objective-C, but are you sure you want to increment the pointer and not the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSInteger` is not a class, it's a `typedef` for `int`. You cannot put it into collections like `NSArray` directly.

You need to wrap your basic data types (`int`, `char`, `BOOL`, `NSInteger` (which expands to `int`)) into `NSNumber` objects to put them into collections.

`NSInteger` does work with `+=`, keep in mind that your code uses pointers to them, which is probably not what you want anyway here.

So

```
NSInteger a = 1, b = 2; 
a += b;
```

would work.

If you put them with `[NSNumber numberWitInt:a];` etc. into an `NSArray`, this is not that easy and you need to use `-intValue` methods to extract their values first.

Comment: On 64 bit architectures NSInteger is a typedef to a long. You should always use the appropriate `NSNumber` methods: `numberWithInteger:` and `integerValue` for wrapped NSIntegers.

Answer (score 2):

If totalhours actually contains NSNumber objects you need the following:

```
NSInteger result = 0;
for(NSNumber* n in totalhours)
{
    result += [n integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are confusing NSInteger (a typedef for `int` or `long`) with a class instance such as `NSNumber`.

If your `totalhours` object is an array of `NSNumber` objects, you'll need to do:

```
NSInteger result;
for (NSNumber *hour in totalhours)
{
    result += [hour integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem using the '+=' operator, just be sure about the objects you are working with...
Your code might be :

```
NSNumber *n; NSUInteger t = 0;
for(n in totalHours) {
    t += [n integerValue];
}
// you got your total in t...
```

Answer (score -2):

The += operation definitly works. All you need to do is initialize your `result` variable so it has a start value.
E.g. `NSInteger * result = 0;`

Good luck!

Comment: NSInteger is a base type, `NSInteger*` is a pointer type, so arithmetic works differently.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is probably that you're using a pointer to an NSInteger instead of an actual NSInteger. You're also not initializing it. Try this:

```
NSInteger result = 0;
for (NSInteger * hour in totalhours)
{
    result += *hour; 
}
```

Comment: This still isn't quite right, it is very unlikely (but not impossible) for `totalhours` to contain raw NSInteger pointers.